# Showing something is a composition series and therefore V has infinitely many composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A = M_2(\Bbb Q)$ and $V = A$ as an $A$-module. For $a \in \Bbb Q$, let $e_a$ = $$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & a  \\
>     0 & 0  \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> i) Show that $0 \subset Ae_a \subset V$ is a composition series.
>
> ii) Hence deduce that $V$ has infinitely many composition series.

My thoughts:

I can set up a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ and multiply it by $e_a$, does it then suffice to just show that this new matrix is an $A$ sub module? How would I do this?

For part (ii) I could use the fact that the matrix found in part (i) can hold infinitely many different values.

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: A submodule of $V$ would be a subset, not merely an element (a matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show $Ae_\alpha$ is a simple module and $A/Ae_\alpha$ is a simple module.  This should not be hard considering dimensions.

You’re right that the fact $\alpha$ can be different things gives you many different.submodules. Try to show that $Ae_\alpha\neq Ae_\beta$ when $\beta\neq\alpha$

Comment: How would i should they are simple modules?

Comment: @johnsmith You prove they have no nontrivial submodules. One of my favorite methods is to show that for every nonzero $x,y\in S$, there exists $r\in A$ such that $rx=y$.  You can show that is equivalent to simplicity. Another way is to show that $M_2(\mathbb Q)$ only has a single simple left module up to isomorphism, and it's 2 dimensional over $\mathbb Q$. Obviously then any strictly smaller submodule would have to have dimension $1$ or $0$, and $1$ is impossible.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that M has only a single simple left module up to isomorphism? Is it related to the fact that every A module of dimension 1 is a simple module?

Comment: @johnsmith I mean that, for a matrix ring over a field, all simple left modules are isomorphic to each other. I don’t see any relationship to the fact you cited.